# Shelve out of overflow pages on macos sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, macos-sierra, shelve

While writing to a shelve object I encountered a problem, where I cannot write more records. I get `HASH: Out of overflow pages.  Increase page size` followed by `_dbm.error: cannot add item to database`. Problem occurs on both macos Sierra and earlier os x el capitan. I use python3, anaconda version. The same code works on ubuntu without problems.
Is there some 3rd party module that would work like shelve, but actually work on OSX? This would be a great workaround before getting it to actually work. I'm working with `tinydb` now, but it's not quite the same.

Comment: What is the output of `python3 --version`?

Comment: `python --version`  
`Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)`

Comment: Please consider showing us a [mcve] and the full exception error messages.